# Apache Click Model properties are not rendering

Tags: java, apache, click-framework

I am new to Apache Click Framework and trying to execute HelloWorld example.
I am using click-2.3.0.jar. 
http://click.apache.org/docs/user-guide/html/ch01.html.

I configured web.xml , click.xml as per

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-apacheclick/.

As per the example in the Page class adding the parameter to the `addModel("time", time);` 
and printing in HTML. instead of printing the time , it prints the variable `$time`.I tried with 
`${time}`.

Answer (score 0):

> The template path should have an .htm extension which is specified in web.xml to route *.htm requests to the ClickServlet. [1]

Maybe you named you file with html extension.

[1] [http://click.apache.org/docs/user-guide/htmlsingle/click-book.html#chapter-pages]](http://click.apache.org/docs/user-guide/htmlsingle/click-book.html#chapter-pages%5d)